# Bais representation, from decimal or binary

Tags: binary

How does one go from base 10 or a binary signed magnitude to a desired bias?

any forms of examples will be helpful

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: for instance say I have the decimal number -56, how would I represent that in Bias 128?

Comment: I presume you mean something like [this](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/bias.html)? In which case it tells you at the end how to do it. Add on your bias, then convert to unsigned binary.

Comment: @jippie I don't think he means **base**. I think he means **bias/excess** notation.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I only found references to base in quick google search, but fair enough I rolled it back. I guess I misunderstand the question then.

Comment: Huh? What is a "bias" in this context? Closing this mess.

Comment: http://casdc.ee.ncku.edu.tw/class/CA/CH02.pdf

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com would have been a better place to ask

Answer (score 3):

After a quick bit of google searching I presume you are referring to **Bias/Excess** notation. Never come across it until now, but there is a reference [here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/bias.html).

According to this reference, the notation is a way of representing numbers in binary such that the most negative value is represented by `b000...00` and the most positive value by `b111...11`. This is achieved by adding a "Bias" to the numbers so that when represented in binary they are offset by the correct amount.

The process as explained at the bottom of the linked page is a simple case of:

1. Add on your bias value
2. Convert to binary (unsigned)

Both those steps are relatively straight forward so I am not going to explain them - addition we all know, and there are many many many explanations around of conversion from decimal (base 10) to binary (base 2).

---

In the case of your example in the comments, converting \$-56\$ to a binary number biased at \$128\$ is a simple case of (assuming an 8-bit output):

$$N = -56 + K = -56 + 128 = 72$$
$$B = \mathrm{base_2}(72) = b01001000$$